# How to format this string in c# to show resulet in message box?

Tags: c#

I have a string like below that comes as a response.
I want this string to format so every parameter come one after another.
Like if i get this string

```
string  str1 = @"testmode=0<br>MessageReceived=Your order dispached and will be delived<br>Messagecount1
<br>could not access file: Error=Not enough credit send.";
```

i want to format it so that it look like

```
testmode=0
message received=Your order dispached and will be delivered
message count=1
could not access file:
error=not enough credit send.
```

Comment: `str1.Split(new string[]{"<br>", ":"})`

Comment: Is the message in `html` format ? if its `XHTML`, it should be `</br>`

Comment: API returns that sort of message only that i need to format..not html tag there

Comment: @Sayse, that will make an array of strings... i assume (emphasis on assume) that the OP wants it formatted using newlines...

Comment: @DavidColwell - Ah touché

Comment: Is there meant to be a <br> tag between the : and Error=
If not, then my answer wont work unless you add another clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like

```
string formatted = str1.Replace("<br>",Environment.NewLine);
```

This will just replace the `<br>` tags with a newline.

Comment: And how do you get the last wanted line?

Comment: Good point. I kind of assumed that the test data given had a fault in it.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
MessageBox.Show(str1.Replace(@"<br>", Environment.NewLine));
```

I'm not sure regarding the line break after `could not access file:`
How do you know you have to break line there?

Comment: use the colon for the last bit (replace : with ":\n")

Comment: Not entrely sure why you are using a messagebox... but the code looks like it will work

Comment: @DavidColwell, The header says message box

Comment: And how do you get the last wanted line?

Comment: @Fuex
That depends. How should you know that there should be a new line? Does every colon (:) marks a new line?

Comment: Yes, but as you can see it's the only colon present in the whole string.

Comment: I can see that, but this string is an example, what if on another response the message recieved = your order was delivered at 10:00 AM today.
Should that be a new line as well?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this using Replace to change br into newline. Put after your code this line:

```
str1.Replace("<br>", "\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best one, but what about:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, str1.Split(new string[]{"<br>", ":"}, StringSplitOptions.None)));
```

Comment: @Fuex, if you go with split you might as well add the formatting back to one string in order to send it to MessageBox